# How to beat the final boss from Momodora II?

Tags: momodora-ii

[Momodora II](http://www.elektrobear.com/rdein/momodora2.html) is a 2D-platformer *metroidvania*-style game. According to [TIGSource](http://www.tigsource.com/2011/07/14/momodora-ii/), it was inspired by [Cave Story](http://www.cavestory.org/). And I'm having trouble with the last boss fight.

Warning, spoilers ahead!

> I'm now at the final room (at least I think it is the final one, it is the one with red stairs and a red chair) and I meet the boss woman (the one with little horns). I can defeat her shadow form, but I don't know how to defeat her second form. All my attacks don't seem to cause any damage to her.

Any hints on how to defeat this boss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to play tennis with her when she shoots a big light ball at you - hit it back at her. Expect the pace to become more tense with each beat. A total of 3 rounds and you see the ending!

Comment: Thanks! It feels like a game design mistake to introduce this new mechanic at the very end, right when we are struggling to survive, with low health, and after attacking the boss continuously for a few minutes. If at least any other enemy or minor boss had to be defeated this way, it wouldn't feel wrong and I wouldn't have been stuck.